# Data from Localstorage load any other page, expect app-component page

Tags: angular, frontend

I have a shopping card which a sidebar, and in app-component i have navbar. And when i toggle button on navbar.The app-component where the navbar located, toggle card.component. Everything is working, but for some reason its not works in the app-component. The card.component actually renderes, i see only static template. Although, if I proceed any other page and toggle the card, it shows data, and data comes independently from localstorage. And if i set toggle boolean in the app-component to true by default. I see my card from localstorage. But if retoggle it some reason not shows data. I don't clue why it works like that. But if retoggle it some reason not works. I don't have a clue why it works like that. Though, if i go any other page, the ngIf condition is works. There is something i didn't know, i have no clue.

card.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {faClose, faMinus, faPlus} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  card: any
  closeIcon = faClose
  minusIcon = faMinus
  plusIcon = faPlus

totalSum: number = 0
minus: boolean = false
plus: boolean = true



removeFromCard(index: any){
if(index ===0){
  index = this.card.length
}
  let i = this.card.length - index
    if(index > -1){
    this.card.splice(i, 1)
    }

if(this.card[0] === null || this.card[0] === undefined){
  localStorage.removeItem("card")
}else {
  localStorage.setItem("card", JSON.stringify(this.card))
}
}

getCardPrice(card: any){
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 0;i<card.length;i++){
      this.totalSum = sum + card[i].totalCardPrice * card[i].quantity   
    }
  this.totalSum = sum
  }

getQuantity(index: any, quant: boolean){
for(let i = 0;i<this.card.length; i++){
  if(i === index){
   if(this.card[i].quantity > 0 && this.card[i].quantity !== 0){
    if(quant){
      this.card[i].quantity = +this.card[i].quantity + 1
     } else {
      if(this.card[i].quantity - 1 !== 0){
        this.card[i].quantity = +this.card[i].quantity - 1
      }else {
        this.card[i].quantity = this.card[i].quantity 
      }
     }
   }
  }
}
this.getCardPrice(this.card)
}


  constructor(){
    this.card = localStorage.getItem("card") 
    if(this.card === null){
    this.card = null
    console.log(this.card)
    }else {
      this.card = JSON.parse(this.card)
 
      console.log("not null", this.card)
    }

  }

@Input() isCard: boolean = false
@Output() toActive = new EventEmitter<boolean>()

ngOnInit(){

}

isCloseCard(e:any){
  return false
}

block(event: any){
  event.stopPropaganation()
}
}
```

card.component.html

```
<main >
    <div class="dummy" (click)="toActive.emit(true)">
    </div>
    <section (click)="block($event)">
        <div class="header"><div class="name"><h1>Корзина</h1><p *ngIf="card != null">{{card.length}}</p></div><span (click)="toActive.emit(true)"></span></div>

        <div class="card" *ngIf="card != null && card.length > 0">
            <div class="wrap" *ngFor="let product of card; let i = index">
                <img src="{{product.option.selectedOption.img}}">
                <div class="card-detail">
                  <header> <a routerLink="/order">{{product.product.title}}</a> <span><fa-icon [icon]="closeIcon" (click)="removeFromCard(i)"></fa-icon></span></header>
                  <div class="detail">
                    <div class="option" *ngIf="product.option && product.option.selectedOption">
                        <span>{{product.option.name}}:</span><p>{{product.option.selectedOption.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option">
                        <span>Переключатели:</span><p>{{product.switch}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" *ngIf="product.switchLube !== 'Нет, спасибо!'">
                        <span>Смазка свитчей:</span><p>{{product.switchLube}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" *ngIf="product.tapeMode !== 'Нет, спасибо!'">
                        <span>Tape мод:</span><p>{{product.tapeMode}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="option" *ngIf="product.soundDumping !== false &&     product.soundDumping !== ''">
                        <span>Шумоподавление:</span><p>Да, +5000тг</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="total">
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <div class="control minus" (click)="getQuantity(i, minus)"><fa-icon   [icon]="minusIcon"></fa-icon></div>
                        <div class="quant">{{product.quantity}}</div>
                                <div class="control plus" (click)="getQuantity(i, plus)"><fa-icon         [icon]="plusIcon"></fa-icon></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sum">{{product.quantity * product.totalCardPrice}}тг</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

app-component.ts

```
  cardActive(){
  if(this.isCard === false){
    this.isCard = true 

  }
    else {
      this.isCard = false
    }
  }

  isCardClose(card: boolean){
  this.isCard = false
  console.log("Working")
  }



ngOnInit(){
     }
```

app-component.html isCardClose() callback function to close sidebar card

```
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet>
  </router-outlet>
  <app-card *ngIf="isCard" [isCard]="isCard" (toActive)="isCardClose($event)"></app-card>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>

</div>
```

I know that problem is here. But why it works in other pages?

```
    <div class="card" *ngIf="card != null && card.length > 0">
        <div class="wrap" *ngFor="let product of card; let i = index">
            <img src="{{product.option.selectedOption.img}}">
            <div class="card-detail">
              <header> <a routerLink="/order">{{product.product.title}}</a> <span><fa-icon [icon]="closeIcon" (click)="removeFromCard(i)"></fa-icon></span></header>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="option" *ngIf="product.option && product.option.selectedOption">
                    <span>{{product.option.name}}:</span><p>{{product.option.selectedOption.name}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <span>Переключатели:</span><p>{{product.switch}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="option" *ngIf="product.switchLube !== 'Нет, спасибо!'">
                    <span>Смазка свитчей:</span><p>{{product.switchLube}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="option" *ngIf="product.tapeMode !== 'Нет, спасибо!'">
                    <span>Tape мод:</span><p>{{product.tapeMode}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="option" *ngIf="product.soundDumping !== false &&     product.soundDumping !== ''">
                    <span>Шумоподавление:</span><p>Да, +5000тг</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="total">
                <div class="quantity">
                    <div class="control minus" (click)="getQuantity(i, minus)"><fa-icon   [icon]="minusIcon"></fa-icon></div>
                    <div class="quant">{{product.quantity}}</div>
                            <div class="control plus" (click)="getQuantity(i, plus)"><fa-icon         [icon]="plusIcon"></fa-icon></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sum">{{product.quantity * product.totalCardPrice}}тг</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So, sorry for my english btw. Hope you guys help me, thanks

Comment: I fixed it i gave to the active class to the main container in the app-template when toggle card. And in css gave z-index -1. Funny part i checked it in dev tools there was no element, and when i remove my iterated card and fill with static. it was display ok without z index -1 for whole app